# How to Force SSL redirect Using Nuxt 3 middleware?

Tags: express, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to set up a Nuxt 3 middleware to force HTTPS for all traffic. However, I'm having issues with my code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code I have so far:

```
  export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    if (process.server) {

    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
  
    var  host = nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event?.node?.req?.headers?.host;
    var  protocol = nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event?.node?.req?.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];
    var  url = nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event?.node?.req?.url;
    console.log('host', host, 'protocol', protocol, 'url', url, nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event?.node?.req?.headers);
    if (protocol === 'http') {
      const httpsUrl = `https://${host}${url}`;
      return navigateTo(httpsUrl)

    }
   }
  });
```

Comment: Why are you exposing the application directly to the world, run a revers proxy and manage SSL and redirection from http to https.

Answer (score 1):

In server middleware create file 0.redirect.ts

```
export default defineEventHandler(async(event) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  const host = getRequestHeader(event, 'host')
  const url = event.node.req.url
  const protocol = getRequestProtocol(event)
  const forceDomain = `https://${host}`
  if (protocol === 'http' && config.enviroment === 'production') {
    await sendRedirect(event, `${forceDomain}${url}`, 301)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import redirectSSL from 'redirect-ssl'
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const protocol = event.node.req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']; // http || https
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV; // development || production
  if (protocol === 'http' && env === 'production') {
    return redirectSSL(event.node.req, event.node.res)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, while your answer may address the question, it's better to provide explanations, docs, or links with supporting informations. We are all here to learn. Read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: That's not gonna work because `protocol` return `IPv6` in Nuxt 3

Answer (score 0):

Here's the instruction on how to implement http/https redirection in Nuxt 3 project using a library [redirect-ssl](https://github.com/unjs/redirect-ssl)

1. Import redirect-ssl `npm i redirect-ssl`
2. Create a file redirect.js in Server->Middleware folder
3. Paste the following code into redirect.js

```
import redirectSSL from 'redirect-ssl'
    
export default fromNodeMiddleware(redirectSSL.create({
enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
}))
```